# Creating a new column by subtracting two other columns that one of them is shifted

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [20, np.nan, np.nan], 'b': [np.nan, 3, 2]})

      a    b
0  20.0  NaN
1   NaN  3.0
2   NaN  2.0
```

And this is the output that I want:

```
      a    b     c
0  20.0  NaN   NaN
1   NaN  3.0  17.0
2   NaN  2.0  15.0
```

I want to subtract column `a` and `b`. For example the second row is 20 - 3 and the last row is 17 - 2. Basically I want to shift one value. That is, I want to subtract by the result of the previous one.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].shift(1) - df.b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].ffill().sub(df['b'].cumsum())
```

Or, if there is only one value in "a":

```
df['c'] = df['b'].cumsum().rsub(df.loc[0, 'a'])
```

Output:

```
      a    b     c
0  20.0  NaN   NaN
1   NaN  3.0  17.0
2   NaN  2.0  15.0
```